# Serial communication drops information on Linux, but not on Windows

Tags: python, linux, windows, serial-port

The problem is, that I use a device (ISDT CM1620) for charging my batteries.
I want to automate the start of the charging via a simple button.

The device offers a simple protocol described on their page https://www.isdt.co/support?lang=en at "Open source"

I tried Python with "pyserial" and Kotlin with "jSerialComm" and got the same result.
If I run it on a Windows machine it works without any problem, but as soon as I switch to my raspberry with raspbian or to my PC with ubuntu it no longer works reliable.
As soon as I receive longer payloads all or parts of the message I receive are dropped.

What I have found out is that the device automatically detects the baud rate and windows using the "usbser" driver to handle the communication. On my raspberry pi, I just plugged it in and used the "/dev/ttyACM0" file for communication.
I also tried flow control (xonxoff, rtscts, dsrdtr and none), but it did not solve the problem.

Have anyone an idea what I am missing?

Here is a part of my python implementation:

```
import serial
import argparse
import io
import sys

def isNL(str):
    return str == "\n" or str == "\r"

class Charger:
    def __init__(self, port):
        self.ser = serial.Serial(port, 2560000, timeout = 0.2)
        self.sio = io.TextIOWrapper(io.BufferedRWPair(self.ser, self.ser), "utf-8")


    def readFrame(self):
        text = ""
        byte = ""
        last = ""
        while not(isNL(byte) and isNL(last)):
            text += byte
            last = byte
            byte = self.sio.read(1)
            if byte == "":
                return []
        if text == "":
            return []
        return text.strip().split("\n")


    def sendCommand(self, line):
        encoded_cmd = "#" + line + "\r\n"
        self.sio.write(encoded_cmd)
        self.sio.flush()

    def request(self, line):
        for i in range(300):
            self.sendCommand(line)
            frame = self.readFrame()
            if len(frame) > 0:
                return frame
            print("retry")
        sys.exit(-1)

    def login(self):
        block = self.request("login null")
        return block[1:]


    def hello(self):
        block = self.request("hello")
        return block[1:]


def print_serial(name):
    global ser
    print(name)
    charger = Charger(name)
    status = charger.hello() #waits indefinitely because it waits for a message that has been dropped and tries again after a timeout and so on.
    print(status)

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-p","--port",required = True, help = "Enter Port Name")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

PORT = args['port']
print_serial(PORT)
```

EDIT:

Due to the fact, that the software works find on Windows i have installed windows 10 on my raspberry.
But it seems it does not depend on the operating system, because the same effects of dropping bytes and missing frames appear there as well. Until now the implementation and shipped software from the manufacturer only worked on that one windows laptop, which I can not use as my server.

Comment: what flow control is used?

Comment: I have tried: xonxoff, rtscts, dsrdtr and none, but it did not solve the problem

Comment: I don't know if this is useful, but when had the same problem, the answer was that two processes were consuming the data.

Comment: Good idea, but i have set up a fresh raspbian OS. I can't imagine what other process should consume the data. 

Comment: I checked with `lsof /dev/ttyACM0` and no other process is using that file.

Comment: Perhaps it takes overhead because it always reads one byte at a time? If you have multiple bytes stored in the buffer using [in_waiting](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html#serial.Serial.in_waiting), why not read that many before processing?

Comment: For that reason, I tried the `io.BufferedRWPair` for buffering.
I have now tried your suggestion for reading the pending bytes at once but once again the same behavior.